# I want to trim the names in SQL. for eg. my data has one name as American Airlines and same as "American airlines"

Tags: sql, oracle, substr

I want to trim the names in SQL. for eg. my data has one name as American Airlines and same as "American airlines.
I am looking forward to write a sql query

```
select customer_name, requests.
from Table1.
where code = "blue"
```

--output:

```
American airlines 25
Alaska Airline 45
American airlines 6
```

looking for output

```
American airlines 31
Alaska Airline 45
```

Can someone please help.:)
Thank you

Comment: Ohh, while I was posting the question. "" got deleted. so one of the customer name is American airlines and it another record with "American airline" - there is " at the start and end of the name. so the group by will just group by American airline and "American airlines" I wish to see them summed up.

Comment: Strings need to be enclosed in single quotes `'` in SQL. `"blue"` is a column name in that context, `'blue'` is a string constant

Comment: Your edit has removed the double-quotes from the output completely, so now it looks like simple aggregation; but it's still in the title and part of the question body. So it's even less clear now. You should probably be preventing this situation arising though, e.g. normalising data on input.

Answer (score 1):

Use replace for replacing the " with null

```
REPLACE(string1, string_to_replace, replacement_string)
```

e.g.

```
select replace(customer_name,'"','') as cusname ,sum(requests)
.....
group by cusname
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `group by` with `sum` ??

```
select replace(customer_name,'"','') as customer_name, sum(requests)
from Table1.
where code = "blue"
group by replace(customer_name,'"','');
```